# How to select part of "select"

Tags: html, select

I've got two multiple select lists

```
<html><head></head>
<body>

<select name="cars" multiple="multiple" size="7">
  <option value="">-</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<select name="drivers" multiple="multiple" size="7">
  <option value="1">Luiza</option>
  <option value="2">Sebastian</option>
  <option value="3">John</option>
  <option value="4">Arthur</option>
  <option value="5">Staszek</option>
  <option value="6">Patryk</option>
  <option value="7">Lucas</option>
  <option value="8">Madlen</option>
  <option value="9">Bartek</option>
  <option value="10">Inter</option>
</select>
</body></html>
```

I have to select "drivers" depending on the "cars"

For example, when i select Volvo it atumatically should select Luiza, John and Staszek.
If i select saab, i must have selected Arthur, Inter, Lucas, Patryk

And if it is not possible, then after selecting from the "cars" select "drivers" should be disabled, and when i select "-" from "Cars", "drivers" should be active again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do this with ajax and load the data from database if it is possible.
or try this with jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {     
            $('#a2').attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $('#a1').change(function() {
                var str = "";
                $("#a1 option:selected").each(function () {
                    str += $(this).text() + " ";
                });
                if(str.trim()=="-")
                    $('#a2').removeAttr("disabled");
                else
                    $('#a2').attr("disabled", "disabled");
            });
 });
```

and give id for case as "a1" and drivers for "a2"

Answer (score 1):

Whith jQuery you can do it easyly :

```
      $(document).ready(function (){
        $('#select-cars').change(function(){
            var car = $('#select-cars').val();
            // Uncheck ALL driver
            $('#select-drivers option').each(function (index, value) {
                $(this).removeAttr('selected');
            });
            // Check each driver in funcition of the car
            if (car == 'volvo') {
                //check Luiza etc
                $('#select-drivers option[value=1]').attr('selected', 'true');
            } else if (car == 'saab') {

            }

        });
    });
```